# How can I package a css file with a single module flask application with setuptools?

Tags: python, css, flask, setuptools

Given a simple flask application that is organized like so:

```
app_repo/
--> flask_app.py
--> custom.css
--> setup.py
--> MANIFEST.in
```

I'd like to package this for release on PyPi but am having trouble packaging the css file alongside the app.

The setup.py file looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myapp',
    version='1',
    py_modules=['flask_app'],
    data_files=[('', ['custom.css'])],
    entry_points={'console_scripts':
                  ['runapp = flask_app:app.run_server']},    
)
```

I also include the custom.css file in the MANIFEST.in file.

Inside flask_app.py I have a line like:

```
CSS_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'custom.css')
```

which lets me route the css file using Flask's send_from_directory.

When developing the application from the repository directory and running flask, the css file is found by the app and everything works correctly. But when I package the app using python setup.py sdist the css file is not placed adjacent to flask_app.py and is thus not found.

On unix the data_files entry in setup.py causes the installed files to be like so:

```
/usr/local/custom.css
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_app.py
```

But I'd like the following so that it mirrors the repository functionality:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/custom.css
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_app.py
```

Is there a way have a non-package single file flask application that can be installed and run from the entry point that ensures the css file is in the same directory as where the python module is installed?

I know that I could create a package, put the app and css file in the package and then make use of package_data in the setup.py file, but I'm looking for a solution that allows me to not make any packages.

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick for placing data files into site packages dir, but it relies on:

1. building wheels (so source distributions are a no-go)
2. undocumented behaviour of `bdist_wheel`, so beware this trick can stop working with future versions of `wheel` package.

Change the target dir of `custom.css` to `/`:

```
setup(
    data_files=[('/', ['custom.css'])],
    ...
)
```

Why does this work? This is an undocumented behaviour of `wheel`: normally, when you build and install a source distribution (for example, a `.tar.gz` or a `.zip`), the data files are placed to the target dir specified, so for example `data_files=[('/etc', ['hosts'])]` would overwrite the system's `/etc/hosts` file (assuming you have the root permission). As you can see, the system damage can get arbitrary bad, so `wheel` avoids this by relativizing absolute paths: in the example above, `hosts` will be written not to `/etc`, but to `/path/to/python/site-packages/etc`. This is what is being used in the trick: data files that should be written to system root (`/`) will be written to site packages.

However, this is not documented anywhere, so it may change in future. Keep an eye on [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/issues/92) for a final resolution.

Also, keep in mind that if you build a source dist instead of a wheel (via `python setup.py sdist`), it is possible to install it so that `custom.css` is written to the system root instead of site packages:

```
$ pip install myapp --no-binary=myapp
```

Another thing: instead of resolving the file path relative to the `flask_app.py`, you can use `pkg_resources` so you don't need to fiddle with path strings:

```
from pkg_resources import Requirement, resource_filename
CSS_PATH = resource_filename(Requirement.parse('myapp'), 'custom.css')
```

Comment: This is a very helpful workaround. I'm going to wait and see if there are other options that work with sdist and that would be more reliable before checking as the answer. Thanks.